# Pdf with layers from photoshop CS6

Tags: layers, cs6, pdf, export

Is it possible to export a PSD photoshop file to PDF keeping the layers like in here?

[image]

I tried saving as PDF and checked 'layers', but it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Photoshop failing to retain the PDF layers: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/874382

Comment: it doesnt help, layers are in PDF but that menu in left is missing so i cant hide/show layers :/

Comment: `View > Show/Hide > Navigation Panes > Layers` To see the pane, but as I commented, Photoshop doesn't seem to show layers in Acrobat.

Comment: doesnt help... http://i.imgur.com/Q8hmiyj.png there are no layers

Comment: As I commented.... **It appears to be a bug**. Click the link I added in my first comment.

Comment: so if i try another version of photoshop.. it will work ?

Comment: Doubtful. It doesn't work in Photoshop CC either.

Comment: finaly... adobe ilustrator CS6 can do it :)